# How can I play video over my LAN?

Tags: wi-fi, video, lan

I have a Mythbuntu computer on my home LAN where I store all my music and video files.

I'd like to be able to watch video that is stored on my Mythbuntu computer on my Galaxy Tab 10.1. The videos are in a variety of formats and sizes. I understand that some sizes might be too large to stream over the LAN, but I think it should be within the ability of most hardware.

The Galaxy tab connects via wifi to the home network.

I have tried some apps that claim to be MythTV front ends, but they have proven to be difficult to set up in that they require a lot of MythTV specific settings.

I'm looking for a solution that is independent from MythTV, and just plays the video files in an independant player, much like I would open a video file on my desktop computer with VLC.

Is that possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Isn't MythTV uPnP compatible? If so, you could use any uPnP client, like e.g. [BubbleUPnP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp).

Comment: @Izzy: BubbleIPNP worked like a charm. Make that an answer and I'll green check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [MythTV](http://www.mythtv.org/) is uPnP compatible, you can use any [uPnP client for Android](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=upnp&c=apps). A great app for this purpose is e.g. [BubbleUPnP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp), which not only serves as a client (so you can access what MythTV provides), but also as a server, so you can use it even the other way around and integrate it as a "media provider" with your MythTV installation. This way you are also able to stream media contents from your Android device to your other uPnP capable home devices.

[image: BubbleUPnP: Select renderer] [image: BubbleUPnP: Select media source]
<sup>BubbleUPnP: Where to output, what to play (Source: Google Play; click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

[AirPlayIt](http://www.airplayit.com/blog/tutorials/video-streaming-software-for-andriod-phone.htm) is one software solution that will stream video files from your computer or file server to an Android device. It simply streams things Android can play and transcodes things it can't.

[Plex](http://plexapp.com/) is another popular solution.

You might also investigate any number of UPNP media streaming solutions.

Answer (score 0):

VLC for Android!
This is the port of VLC media player to the Android™ platform. VLC for Android can play any video and audio files, as well as network streams, network shares and drives, and DVD ISOs, like the desktop version of VLC.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc